# Действие над UIView из Subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

```
-(void)test {

  self.view.alpha = 0.4;

}
```

Если это выполнять из класса view, над которым совершаются действия, все работает; если делегировать другому классу, то выполняется, но не работает. Что сделать чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Если делегировать другому классу, то он должен знать путь до view, над которым нужно выполнять действие. Либо в делегате передать view и в делегированном классе обрабатывать его.

Comment: в основном в делегированном методе передают сам объект, имхо второй вариант лучше. Я-бы так сделал